# Trying to create a Picture in picture using farseer and camera2d

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

I am working on a game where the main screen in on one camera.
What i want is to have a small box on the screen working as a monitor or a picture-in-picture showing another area.

How can i set the second camera(the PIP one) to be contained in a square?
Do i need to cut what are on the sides myself or there is a way the camera can handle it?

Comment: You don't need to cut things yourself. You just need to render twice. First render the scene using the PIP camera to a rendertarget2d (which is pretty much rendering to a texture instead of to the backbuffer). Then render the scene to the backbuffer using the main camera. Finally draw the rendertarget2d as a texture to the backbuffer where you want it, eg the top right corner.

Comment: I'm still learning and can't think this way... :(
This works great ty.

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with Farseer.

Comment: @craftworkgames You're partially right. This isn't necessarily related to Farseer, however I believe that OP got his Camera class from the Farseer examples. Hence, the tag.

Comment: @Bjarke Søgaard Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Danfus Figured. You should know, that while you did get the camera class from the Farseer examples, the problem you're facing is related to all 2D cameras in general.